# Is it possible to skip one package update?

Tags: chocolatey

Sometimes Chocolatey package maintainers lag behind and I update a program manually. I can use a command `choco pin add -n=packagename` to lock a package to its current revision, but I must remember to remove the "pin" afterwards or I won't be notified of any subsequent updates.

When Chocolatey notifies me of an update, is it possible to I ignore only this specific version for good?

Comment: I think folks don't understand your question fully, I know I'm having trouble. If you can provide an example of exactly what you are trying to do, that would be helpful (like walk through the process).

Comment: @ferventcoder: I want to ignore one specific package update. For example the latest version of [MSI Afterburner](https://chocolatey.org/packages/msiafterburner) took some time to arrive, I updated manually and would have wanted to *only* skip the next update, not any following.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not following what you mean by skip the next update, not any following. I am starting to feel more like I understand, but it would be very helpful to draw it out explicitly with an example in your question.

Comment: @ferventcoder: A program is updated to version 2.0. Even a month later, the program still has outdated 1.0 version on Chocolatey. I update manually. I want to skip only the upcoming (2.0) update in Chocolatey and nothing more.

Comment: @ferventcoder: I have no understood that this request is so pointless that I will likely delete the question after you have seen my comments — unless there's a suitable command and you can answer the question, of course.

Comment: No need to delete, but possibly updating the question with this information in the comments would reframe it better for answering.